# Reformat a large text file into one line strings (via BASH)

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, cat

File1:

```
hello
- dictionary definitions:
hi
hello
hallo
greetings
salutations
no more hello for you
-
world
- dictionary definitions:
universe
everything
the globe
the biggest tree
planet
cess pool of organic life
-
```

I need to format this (for a huge list of words) into a term to definition format (one line per term). How can one achieve this? None of the words are the same, only the structure seen above is. The resultant file would look something like this:

```
hello    - dictionary definitions:    hi    hello    hallo    greetings    salutations    no more hello for you    -
world    - dictionary definitions:    universe    everything    the globe    the biggest tree    planet    cess pool of organic life    -
```

Awk/Sed/Grep/Cat are the usual contenders.

Comment: Changed question to be more scripting language/command specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\n"; RS="-\n"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s   ",$i); if($1)print"-";}' dict.txt
```

outputs:

```
hello   - dictionary definitions:   hi   hello   hallo   greetings   salutations   no more hello for you   -
world   - dictionary definitions:   universe   everything   the globe   the biggest tree   planet   cess pool of organic life   -
```

Comment: I love you man! That is a friggin' huge command - and it works perfectly.

Comment: Note if you need to handles empty line at the end of the file you will need to add an if: `awk 'BEGIN {FS="\n"; RS="-\n"}{if(NF>2){for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf("%s   ",$i);print("-");}}' dict.txt`

Answer (score 3):

and who says only Perl can do it elegantly ? :)

```
$ gawk -vRS="-\n" '{gsub(/\n/," ")}1' file
hello - dictionary definitions: hi hello hallo greetings salutations no more hello for you
world - dictionary definitions: universe everything the globe the biggest tree planet cess pool of organic life
```

OR

```
# gawk 'BEGIN{RS="-\n";FS="\n";OFS=" "}{$1=$1}1'  file
hello - dictionary definitions: hi hello hallo greetings salutations no more hello for you
world - dictionary definitions: universe everything the globe the biggest tree planet cess pool of organic life
```

Comment: don't understand. is it <start><space>bar<space>? or just <bar><space>?

Answer (score 2):

A perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 'chomp;s/^-$/\n/;print " "' File1
```

gives

```
 hello - dictionary definitions: hi hello hallo greetings salutations no more hello for you
 world - dictionary definitions: universe everything the globe the biggest tree planet cess pool of organic life
```

This is 'something like' your required output.

Comment: Nice! More elegant then the one above. I've heard that perl is awesome for its text manipulation abilities.

Comment: Perl is awesome, so is awk, its grand-daddy :)

Comment: Yes, Larry Wall certainly gave credit to `awk`, no doubt about that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the scripting language you will be using, pseudo code here:

```
for each line
 if line is "-"
  create new line
 else
  append separator to previous line
  append line to previous line
 end if
end for loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one liner works on a conditions that theer will always be 6 lines for a word

```
sed 'N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;s/\n/ /g' test_3
```

Comment: not flexible enough. you will never know how many definitions there are

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -ne'1{x;d};/^-$/{g;s/\n/ /g;p;n;x;d};H'
awk -v'RS=\n-\n' '{gsub(/\n/," ")}1'
```